# How do I multiply the value then change the result into a string

Tags: python

Im kinda new to this and I wanna know how do I change this to multiply the value by 100 first then convert the result to a string?

```
print(" You got " + str(score / 5) * 100) + "%.")
```

Comment: What you want is probably this `print(" You got " + str(score / 5 * 100) + "%.")`. `score / 5 * 100` is placed in parenthesis after str so that it is calculated first before being converted to string.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some parentheses:

```py
print("You got " + str((score / 5) * 100) + "%.")
```

But if you're using python 3.6+, I'd use an f-string

```py
print(f"You got {((score / 5) * 100)}%.")
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other correct answers already posted, you could also use a format string to make this a bit cleaner.

```
print(f" You got {(score / 5) * 100}%")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing '(' after str. Use this

```
print(" You got " + str((score / 5) * 100) + "%.")
```